# Unable to embed hyper link in ion-checkbox

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to embed an external link in the ion-checkbox. Neither the click event triggers nor the href of anchor tag is working.Here is my code

```
 <ion-checkbox name="agreement" ng-model="myCtrl.agreement">
    <a href="www.example.com" ng-click="myCtrl.onClickAgreement()">
     and I agree to the Terms and Conditions
    </a>
  </ion-checkbox>
```

This is the controller

```
vm.onClickAgreement = function () {
    window.open("www.example.com",'_system');
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set an `a href` within a checkbox.  What I would imagine you would want is the label next to the checkbox to be the link to the terms and conditions.  Something like the below should do it!

```
<ion-label><a href="http://www.example.com">and I agree to the Terms and Conditions</a></ion-label>
<ion-checkbox name="agreement" ng-model="myCtrl.agreement"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if it's inside an `ion-item`, since clicking the `ion-label` toggles the state of the checkbox.

Comment: doesn't work with `ion-item` wrapping, which is the norm in ionic applications.

Comment: @DaleZak may you can set a div with styles instead of `ion-item`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ion-item` the hyperlink never can be trigger, so instead of that you can use the following code:

```
<div class="conditions">
    <ion-checkbox name="agreement" formControlName="terms" [(ngModel)]="terms">
    </ion-checkbox>
    <a href="http://www.google.cl/">Acepto términos y condiciones</a>
</div>
```

And you need to style them:

```
.conditions{
  padding: 12px;
}

.conditions ion-checkbox{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 8px;
}

.conditions ion-label{
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
```